# Permission denied

Tags: adb, shell

[[ASL]](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) gives this error in library installations:

```
%ANDROID%\platform-tools\adb.exe push %NATIVE% /data/local/asl-native
```

--->RUN

```
'/data/local/asl-native':Permission denied
```

How can I overcome this problem without roots in the device?

Comment: You can't. The `/data` partition is write-protected for any non-system process (including `adb`).

Comment: So how can I do this? not that I've tried a lot of things

Comment: Root your device, type `adb root`, execute your command. If it doesn't work, you will need to change one line in `build.prop`: `ro.adb.secure=1` -> `0`.

Comment: is not it possible to do without the root?

Comment: No, I'm sorry but this is not possible. It is meant to secure the system from unauthorized modifications.

Comment: Do not have any way to give this permission?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not possible without full control (root) on your device

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/data/local/tmp`, does not need root.